# DownloadManager get a file from untrusted url

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, android-download-manager

Hi i'm building an app that one of it's features it to download fiz files with images from a server built by us.
This server responds to HTTPS requests and uses Basic Authentication. When i make a request to the download manager using as the following:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
Header header = BasicScheme.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user","pass"),"UTF-8", false);
request.addRequestHeader(header.getName(), header.getValue());
```

When I query the download manager as of the state of the request i get `status = STATUS_PAUSED` and `reason = PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY`

If i try to open the url on a browser i get the following: "The site's security certificate is not trusted!"

My question is: what's the best way to resolve this issue? I can't find anyway to tell the DownloadManager to trust the url or the certificate. (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3492)

I've seen other similar problems but it regards creating a SSLSocketFactory and placing a keystore with the cert in the Raw folder, I don't like this for 2 reasons, first by unzipping the .apk, the keystore is accessible, second the cert pass has to be in the code and decompiling it and probably some hard work, some ppl may access it. But this will not solve the download manager problem.

Is there a way that when my app is installed, it also installs the cert as trusted on the device?

Thanks for any help on this, and sorry if any of this question seem naive but my knowledge of this topic is very little.

Comment: the keystore you would include is the public key of your certificate,  nothing really confidential

Comment: ok, thanks for the info :) Unfortunately the `SSLSocketFactory` won't solve the download manager problem :(